# MYSQL Get every first id of unique ip's

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has a column with id's and a column with ip addresses. There's other information in the table, but for this problem I'm only focussing on the ip addresses.

I need to figure out every first occurrence of an ip address in the table, and return the id number.

There are many questions similar to this but they are all older questions and their answers don't seem to work for some reason.

Here's an example table:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | ip              |
+----+-----------------+
|   1| 123.45.67.89    |
|   2| 123.45.67.89    |
|   3|  98.76.54.32    |
|   4| 123.45.67.89    |
|   5|  98.76.54.32    |
|   6|  11.22.33.44    |
+----+-----------------+
```

The result I want to get back is (it may have the ip column if that is a requirement):

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|   1|
|   3|
|   6|
+----+
```

But either I get all results back, or I get the last ID back: 4,5,6

What I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`ip`), `id` 
FROM `MyTable`
ORDER BY `id` ASC
-- this gives all rows.

SELECT `id`
FROM `MyTable`
GROUP BY `ip`
ORDER BY `id` ASC
-- this works but seems to completely ignore the ORDER BY statement, I get the last id, instead of first.

SELECT `ip` FROM
(   SELECT `ip`
    FROM `MyTable`
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
) as rows
GROUP BY `ip`
-- the id is not specified here and as such not returned. 

SELECT `ip`, `id` FROM
(   SELECT `ip`, `id`
    FROM `MyTable`
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
) as rows
GROUP BY ip
-- finds the uniques, but again does not sort, so instead returns the last occurence, not the first.
```

How can I get this to work in 2017?

Comment: You don't need it to work next year?

Comment: @Andreas well, every answer I can find is 2013 or earler. It seems the current version of php / mysql just don't work with it. Some comments even state that the group by doesn't sort properly anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
select id from MyTable group by ip order by id
```

If you're really having trouble with ordering, try this:

```
select id from 
(SELECT id
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ip) tmpTable order by id
```

If this doesn't work, there's something wrong with your table definition. Try posting your create statement and any index creation statements.

Also, my table is using the InnoDB engine. What engine are you using? Others may respond differently.

Comment: It could be that. I was using MyISAM, changed it to InnoDB and now I have different results. It might be that this is what stops me... I'm investigating

Comment: Awesome, yes, this did it. Setting it to InnoDB worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do a self join to get the first occurrence of ip

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b on a.ip = b.ip
and a.id > b.id
where b.id is null
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/915b2/2)

Comment: This results in no id's at all. :(

Comment: @LPChip How? can you reproduce that issue on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/915b2/2 ? As per your provided data i have added demo in my answer

Comment: In your demo it does work. I'm now investigating my code to see if something else is going wrong.

Comment: I have found out why its not working. I have another column that I group by, and because I am not using that in my question, your code finds the first occurrence from one of the other groups. I probably can make that work. If I do, I'll accept this answer as it seems to be what I'm after.

Comment: +1 for helping me see another error and providing a good answer with demo. :) It was not the solution, so I can't mark it as answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `id`
from (
    select * from `MyTable` order by `id` ASC
    ) x
group by `ip`
```

Maybe this way?

Comment: Nope. :( As soon as I use a group by , the inner query is ignored, regardless of how I sort it. MySQL optimization FTL in this case.

Comment: You need to provide us complete query

Answer (score 0):

If your IPs table doesnt have more columns, just use this:

```
select distinct(*) from `myTable`
```

Comment: It has, as mentioned in my question.